# Convert .mat to .xls file

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab 6p1 and trying to convert from .mat file to .xls file to edit in OpenOffice spreadsheet but my matlab version not working with xlswrite function. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Undefined function or variable xlswrite
```

Any way to import the function. Any other way to perform conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Matlab version is to old to use this function, check your local documentation which is accessible via `doc` command, it's not present there.

Alternatives:

1. Get a newer version of matlab
2. Write the data to a text based format and import it to excel. Use `fprint`
3. Use octave, which basically supports the same language but is open source.
4. Use python with scipy to load the data.

Comment: I have import to Octave, but I can't see how to export to xls file.

Comment: No, I don't know how to perform operation

Comment: I have one workspace with several matrix and I want to export this matrix to an .xls file to draw graphics and present in a document

Comment: @jgd and where is the problem implementing this? Different sheets and ranges can be specified to write the matrices next to each other.